# How to create a list in Power Query from the listed values in Excel sheet, if it has a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

I am trying to modify the Excel's Power Query with specific rows to keep by using function Table.SelectRows(...). I have the list with numbers of rows to keep and it's working fine, however, I can't make that list dynamic. What I want to achieve is having a cell in Excel sheet which has rows listed as a parameter and to load it in Power Query as a list. 
So those values in Excel look like this

1,4,6..10,20..25

I can load it into PQ but can't generate values in the range - i.e. from 6 to 10 and from 20 to 30, so the list should look like 
1,4,6,7,8,9,10,20,21,22,23,24,25

Was hoping to use **List.Generate(()=>6,each _<=10, each _ +1)** but get and error   after I try to expand it

[link to query look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD4KU.png)

I have a feeling that what I am trying to achieve is doable but kind of stuck. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

**Update:** Solution found - I used **List.Numbers()** which does what I need - creating a list of numbers from starting number

Comment: Since you have not shared Source Data so it's difficult to figure out but I'm sure you have to create parameter in sheet then name them/it. and load it to the query and use `getParameter` formula. Also use `Number.RandomBetween` ,, hope this help you.

Comment: How does Number.RandomBetween can help in this case? I need a list of all numbers b/w first and last ones? Also not sure there is a function getParameter in M, at least I can't find it in the list in msdn site.